# how to open a command prompt(cmd) using bash script and pass arguments in windows

Tags: bash, cmd, hyper

In Ubuntu i use
`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=multi --command="bash -c 'cd ./backend && npm start'"`

In hyper terminal  using `hyper` keyword it opens a terminal but how to pass command arguments.
If above command `--command="bash -c 'cd ./backend && npm start'"` is used
we get
`The option "command" is unknown. Did you mean the following one? -v, --verbose  Verbose mode (disabled by default)`

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean windows terminal, hyper terminal isn't the equivilent of gnome-terminal

Comment: when you get the hyper prompt, try entering    bash -c 'cd ./backend && npm start'   .  I could find no references to options for the hyper command itself, so you might be forced to go interactive, not batch mode.  I could be wrong.